# Change to random background image and corresponding text on click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have a certain amount of images I want to have as backgrounds, full covered, on my site.

To each background image there's a specific text I want to be shown in the center of the screen.

Each background image and its corresponding text should be randomized with a click of a button.

I don't now any JavaScript or jQuery, which seems to be the solution. Though, I havn't found any good code for my problem. Is there a code that would do what i want?

Thanks!

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu7jcz8m/2/) demo of the website.**

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="box">
        <div class="title">TITLE OF WEBSITE</div>
        <div class="text">Text corresponding to the specfic background shown.</div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="button">Randomizing button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#background {
    height: 100%;
}
#box {
    background: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 40%;
    position: relative;
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height:50px;
}
.text {
    background: #c8c8c8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background: #afafaf;
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @vikar The way you've framed the questioned seems to be in better manner. But asking full logic in SO is strictly not entertained. Better you present what you've tried until now and then ask your doubt...

Comment: @Alek I don't have a JavaScript yet. I have found some code, but it  won't work with my HTML and CSS setup on my page.

Comment: @vikar The idea of SO is to help when you get stuck, not to create the whole programm for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cu7jcz8m/9/)

**HTML** (Just added IDs)

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="box">
        <div class="title">TITLE OF WEBSITE</div>
        <div class="text" id="text-box">Text corresponding to the specfic background shown.</div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="button" id="my-button">Randomizing button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myData = { // Create a JSON for your images
    1: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/1",
        text: "This is the text for image 1"
    }, 
    2: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/2",
        text: "This is the text for image 2"
    }, 
    3: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/3",
        text: "This is the text for image 3"
    }, 
    4: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/4",
        text: "This is the text for image 4"
    }, 
    5: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/5",
        text: "This is the text for image 5"
    }, 
    6: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/6",
        text: "This is the text for image 6"
    }, 
    7: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/7",
        text: "This is the text for image 7"
    }, 
    8: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/8",
        text: "This is the text for image 8"
    }, 
    9: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/9",
        text: "This is the text for image 9"
    }, 
    10: {
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/10",
        text: "This is the text for image 10"
    }
};
function changeImage(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); //Change 10 to the number of images in your JSON
    document.getElementById("background").style.background = "url('"+myData[randomNumber].imageUrl+"')";
    document.getElementById("text-box").innerHTML = myData[randomNumber].text;
}

document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click",changeImage); //Bind the button to the changeImage function
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Is it possible to add so that the active background don't get randomized to be shown directly after itself? Is it also possible to make all the backgrounds sizes to "cover" the full page always?

Comment: This is so awesome! I had a quick question on how the "imageUrl" would look if I had all these files locally not using a url. Could I just use /images/test1.jpg?

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cu7jcz8m/6/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="box">
        <div class="title">TITLE OF WEBSITE</div>
        <div class="text" id="text">Text corresponding to the specfic background shown.</div>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="button" id="btn">Randomizing button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var bks=new Array("http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png","http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b");
/* This Array 'bk' will hold the random images you want to set as background */
var desc=new Array("JSFIDDLE LOGO","SO SPRITE");
/* This array 'desc' will hold the description of respective image  want to display */
var bk=document.getElementById("background");
var div=document.getElementById("text");
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var count=0;
function doIT(){
bk.style["background"]="url('"+bks[count]+"') center center";
    div.innerHTML=desc[count];
    count=count?0:1;
    /* To Change the count randomly use :
     count=Math.floor( Math.random() * ( bks.length - 0 ) ) + 0;
      SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/cu7jcz8m/7/
    */
}

btn.addEventListener("click",doIT);
```

Hope it helps. Cheers :)!